# Running Jetty using Maven before Integration Test

Tags: java, maven, junit, jetty, integration-testing

I'm gonna create integration tests for REST API. So, I'd like to run Jetty before tests and stop it after tests. I've got Connection Refused Error for each Tests. My POM.XML's build section is written below:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <port>8010</port>
        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        </connector>
    </connectors>
    <contextPath>/performance-parser-service</contextPath>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
            <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanintervalseconds>0</scanintervalseconds>    
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>performance-parser-service-it</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Could you help me for solving this issue?

Best Regards,

Comment: Are your tests pointing to the correct port? I also remember seeing a plugin that will let you reserve an open port and set a variable that you can pass to both your container and tests...

Comment: Yeap, I checked again and tests point to the 8010, the same port

Answer (score 2):

Integration tests run with `mvn verify`, not `mvn test`.

Comment: Yes, the configuration in the question uses the Surefire plugin (`mvn test`); for integration testing the Failsafe plugin should be used (`mvn verify`). The correct configuration is shown in the [Maven Failsafe Usage Guide](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html#Using_jetty_and_maven-failsafe-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me,
the main differences are: Newer version of the plugin (important: different groupId) and use the goal `start` instead of `run`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.5.v20141112</version>
    <configuration>
        <stopPort>11079</stopPort>
        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        <httpConnector>
            <port>11080</port>
        </httpConnector>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </webApp>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Works for me, the only minor issue was that the daemon element is supposed to be given as part of /plugin/configuration, but not /plugin/executions/execution/configuration XML path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way but I have done this in the past by starting Jetty programatically in the `@BeforeClass` of your tests. See here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html#embedded-one-webapp

Also remember to use a free port to start the server instead of hardcoding some value otherwise tests fail on your CI as port maybe in use on another build. There are many ways for it if you search.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the way that you said and it works; however, i'm looking for Maven solution for that... Anyway, Thanks for your solution.